# Static final field in Java wrapper class unexpectedly returns null

Tags: java, wrapper

I'm facing an issue with a static final field in my `ImportSpecificationWrapper` class. The field `TSV` should hold an instance of `ImportSpecification`, but it's unexpectedly returning null.

I'm using a wrapper class to extend the types of `ImportSpecification` because I'm unable to modify `ImportSpecification`. The relevant classes:

```
public class ImportSpecificationWrapper {

    private final ImportSpecification importSpecification;

    public static final ImportSpecification TSV = new ImportSpecification("TSV", "TSV");

    public ImportSpecificationWrapper(ImportSpecification importSpecification) {

        this.importSpecification = importSpecification;
    }

    public String getType() {

        return importSpecification.getType();
    }

    public String getFriendlyType() {

        return importSpecification.getFriendlyType();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return importSpecification.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof ImportSpecificationWrapper) {
            return importSpecification.equals(((ImportSpecificationWrapper) obj).importSpecification);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static ImportSpecificationWrapper getInstance(String type) {

        if (TSV.getType().equals(type)) {
            return new ImportSpecificationWrapper(TSV);
        }
        return new ImportSpecificationWrapper(ImportSpecification.getInstance(type));
    }

    public static Collection<ImportSpecification> getTypes() {

            return ImportSpecification.getTypes();
    }
}
```

```
public class ImportSpecification implements Serializable, BroadleafEnumerationType {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final LinkedHashMap<String, ImportSpecification> TYPES = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public static final ImportSpecification CSV = new ImportSpecification("CSV", "CSV");
    public static final ImportSpecification JSON = new ImportSpecification("JSON", "JSON");
    public static final ImportSpecification ASSET_ARCHIVE = new ImportSpecification("ASSET_ARCHIVE", "Asset Archive");

    public static ImportSpecification getInstance(final String type) {
        return TYPES.get(type);
    }

    public static Collection<ImportSpecification> getTypes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(TYPES.values());
    }

    private String type;
    private String friendlyType;

    public ImportSpecification() {
        //do nothing
    }

    public ImportSpecification(final String type, final String friendlyType) {
        this.friendlyType = friendlyType;
        setType(type);
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyType() {
        return friendlyType;
    }

    private void setType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
        if (!TYPES.containsKey(type)) {
            TYPES.put(type, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj != null && getClass().isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
            ImportSpecification other = (ImportSpecification) obj;
            return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(type, other.type)
                .build();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I created a static final field named `TSV` in my `ImportSpecificationWrapper` class, which is holds an instance of ImportSpecification with the type `TSV`. I expected that whenever I reference `ImportSpecificationWrapper.TSV`, it would return this instance.

When I try to access `ImportSpecificationWrapper.TSV`, it unexpectedly returns `null`. The initialization of this field does not throw any exceptions and there are no static initializers that might interfere with its initialization.

I attempted to created a [minimum reproducible example here](https://github.com/spencerjstewart/null-wrapper-type-issue), but it actually behaves as expected and returns true here. I cannot reproduce the behavior.

In my project, you can see below that `ImportSpecificationWrapper.TSV` is null.

[image: Null type for ImportSpecificationWrapper.TSV]

[image: Information about the importSpecification object]

I tried adding the following static initialization block inside ImportSpecificationWrapper and `ImportSpecificationWrapper.TSV` no longer returns null:

```
static {
    try {
        Class.forName("path.to.ImportSpecification");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("Could not find class path.to.ImportSpecification");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example and information on how you run that code?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev You can type `[mre]` to easily make that a link: [mre]

Comment: @CcmU I'm not trying to implement a singleton.

Comment: The "R" in MRE stands for reproducible. While it may be helpful for you in contrasting between the working example and your not-working code, it's less helpful for us since all we get is a working piece of code without the problem you describe. Are you using reflection anywhere?

Comment: @Rogue I'm unable to provide a reproducible example then. I would have to allow the public to run our proprietary code on their machine which I can't do. I'm not using reflection.

Comment: @Maksim Eliseev I attempted to recreate the issue, but it behaves as expected in the project I linked in my post in an edit.

Comment: @SpencerStewart, it's so weird, I don't know how to help you

Comment: This could happen, when you try to access a field, when it is not yet created.
As long as the ctor of ImportSpecification has not 'completed', the object (TSV) does not exist! So, check your ctor of ImportSpecification. Maybe ctor of ImportSpecification tries to access this (no yet created) field.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the suggestion. I added a static initialization block inside ImportSpecificationWrapper and called `Class.forName("path.to.ImportSpecification");` and now ImportSpecificationWrapper.TSV is no longer null. Very strange, no clue why this would happen.

Comment: @Maksim Eliseev

It looks like it's due to ImportSpecificationWrapper being loaded before ImportSpecification, I believe. I'm not familiar with how class loading works. I added a static initialization block inside ImportSpecificationWrapper and called `Class.forName("path.to.ImportSpecification");` which fixed the null issue. No clue why there's this discrepancy between the 2 environments.